# How to search Steam game API JSON output?

Tags: javascript, php, steam, steam-web-api

I am working with following APIs:

http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v0002/?format=json

https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=GAMEID
(gameid example: "730"   - counter strike)

My goal with both of these is to search them for data. For example I want the first API to give me a name of a game based on it's ID and the second one to give me specific information about a game for example if it has trading cards (id:29 in the API).

I tried a few things but I am kinda lost on this beacuse I don't really understand JSON so I would really appreciate some help.

I am open to both PHP and JS solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IN PHP, you can use the  `json_decode()` function to convert JSON data into an array. You can them access the values as you do for a classic array :

```
$appID = 730 ;
$url = 'https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=' . $appID ;

$content = file_get_contents($url) ; // retrieve the JSON data string from the website
$data = json_decode($content, true); // convert the JSON string into PHP array 

echo $data[$appID]['data']['name'] ; // Counter-Strike: Global Offensive
var_dump($data[$appID]['data']['is_free']); // bool(true)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer it helped me a lot. However I realized that I also need to implement this feature client-side. Would you happen to know how to replicate this in JS?